# Работа с Python. Модуль subprocess.Pipe

Tags: python, subprocess

Нужно сделать аналог конвейерной команды типа "dmesg | grep", но вклиниться после первой команды и получить вывод, который передастся второй.
Думал так:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["dmesg"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

out1 = p1.stdout.readlines()

p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "sda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

out2, error = p2.communicate()

print(out1)

print(out2)
```

out2 на выходе = ''

Comment: А out1 на выходе что?

Comment: out1 нормальный вывод. Такое ощущение, что после чтения пайпа, он очищается

Comment: Ну тогда передавайте во вторую команду out1, а не p1.stdout, который уже пустой. Или уберите строчку с out1.

Comment: есть команда tee, если делать это без питона)